# MongoDB query FindOne is not working with Nodejs API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Trying to **find a single document** details by id using **POST API** but API returns `error 500` using **MongoDB and Node.js.**

**Schema**

```
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5cad89cabfb35db56688556c"
    },
    "articleid": "c4a3c72a-f4ec-11e7-bec2-b083fe9a696b",
    "md5id": "8e0d6ca665a977cc825bd90dc1751d53",
    "headline": "Stepping up",
    "subtitle": "",
    "type": "PRINT",
}
```

**Model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({

Title: String
 },
{
    collection: 'impactliveupdated'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Model', schema);
```

**controller.js**

```
  articlesById = function (req, res) {
  var articleids = req.body.articleids;
  var query = {

  };
  query.articleid = {
      $in: articleids
  }; 

  articlesModule.findOne(query, function (err, impacts) {
      if (err) {
          console.log("error 6");
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500);
          res.send("internal error");
      } else {
          res.status(200);
          console.log("sending data");
         // console.log(impacts);
          res.json(impacts);
      }
  });
}
```

if possible guide me to correct it I am new in MEAN stack!

Comment: Is articleId in the schema? Not showing in code.

Comment: yes articleId is in document field

Comment: Your schema only shows one field Title. Are you confusing _id with articleid? You can use findById too.

Comment: @TusharShahi I have a field name `articleid` by which i am trying to find, do i need to mention `articleid` in  `Model.js schema` ?

Comment: Ok. Update your schema so others know it too. Also try logging your articleIds variable. Is that an array?

Comment: I am asking to you do I need to Mention `articleid` in my **model.js** and no `articleid` is not an array

Comment: Yes. it is better if you do it. Also, i was asking about articleIds. $in operator works on arrays right. If articleId from the document is inside [articleIds] which is sent in your request body it will return the doc.

Comment: I have updated the code with schemas Please check once @TusharShahi

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need to use $in operator as suggested by @Tusharshahi and you can use direct findOne query.

```
  articlesById = function (req, res) {
  var articleid = req.body.articleid; 

  articlesModule.findOne({articleid:articleid}, function (err, impacts) {
      if (err) {
          console.log("error 6");
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500);
          res.send("internal error");
      } else {
          res.status(200);
          console.log("sending data"); 
          res.json(impacts);
      }
  });
}
```